# How to match qoutes, doubleqoutes parenthesis brackets and braces in vim automatically?

Tags: vim, mapping

I'm starting to use vim in my everyday coding. While I was exploring, I discovered the use of *map. So I decided to add the following mapping to my .vimrc file.

```
inoremap ' ''<left> 
inoremap " ""<left> 
imap ( ()<left>
imap { {}<left>
imap [ []<left>
imap < <><left>
```

The idea is to match every ',",(,{,[,< with its closing equivalent. The problem with that is that the mapping works even if I'm pasting while in insert mode.

```
// Pasting this 
()=>{ console.log("Hello World"); }

//Will result to something like this
())=>{} console.log())""Hello World"");}
```

What can I do to prevent that?

Comment: you probably only want that for certain filetypes. Probably you only do js in vim at the moment, but trust me, in 3 months you want to write everything in vim. Having your mappings in mails or vimscript will be aweful. So i would recommend searching a js plugin which does that.

Comment: Why is it not a good idea to have mapping in .vimrc?

Comment: One example would be vimscript, where the `"` sign is a comment delemiter, another would be normal englisch were you want to write things like `John's house, China's border ...` so adding always two over all filetypes is maybe a bad idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because you are pasting using your terminal emulator or desktop environment's shortcuts instead of Vim's: the text is not "pasted", it is "inserted", just as if you typed it very quickly, and insert mode mappings are triggered.

To prevent that, you can `:set paste` before pasting and `:set nopaste` afterward or you can use Vim's own `y`, `p`, and `P` commands.

For the first option, see `:help 'paste'` and `:help 'pastetoggle'`.

For the second option, see `:help y`, `:help p`, `:help registers`, and `:help 'clipboard'`. Note that you may need a Vim built with clipboard support.

Comment: May be interested in [vim-bracketed-paste](https://github.com/ConradIrwin/vim-bracketed-paste), which handles bracketed-paste-mode in vim (aka. automatic `:set paste`) for compatible terms.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to the [rainbow](https://github.com/luochen1990/rainbow) plugin. It highlights bracket pairs, and indicates the 'depth' you're in by changing the highlight colour.